# netmask: how to calculate number of networks?

Tags: netmask

My way to calculate netmask number of host, for example: i want to know the number of hosts for netmask 255.255.255.192 (prefix 26)

```
255.255.255.192 11111111.11111111.11111111.11000000             26                      128+64=192
```

the 192 is 128+64 of the two "1" bits of the latest octet, the number of host is the number of 0 bits(host part) of the latest octet, so 000000 are 6, so 2^6-2 is 62, and ipcalc confirm is ok

```
ipcalc 10.2.0.1/26
Address:   10.2.0.1             00001010.00000010.00000000.00 000001
Netmask:   255.255.255.192 = 26 11111111.11111111.11111111.11 000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.63             00000000.00000000.00000000.00 111111
=>
Network:   10.2.0.0/26          00001010.00000010.00000000.00 000000
HostMin:   10.2.0.1             00001010.00000010.00000000.00 000001
HostMax:   10.2.0.62            00001010.00000010.00000000.00 111110
Broadcast: 10.2.0.63            00001010.00000010.00000000.00 111111
Hosts/Net: 62                    Class A, Private Internet
```

My question is: how to know/calculate the number of subnets with a prefix..for example 26 or 27?
I have to do the net part(26 "1" bit^2=)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, to calculate subnets, for example for netmask with prefix 29

```
255.255.255.248 11111111.11111111.11111111.11111000             29                      128+64+32+16+8=248
```

we have in the latest octet

```
11111000
```

so, the number of host is  6

```
000=3=2^3-2=6
```

the number of subnets is 32

```
11111=2^5=32
```

This way is ok for class C of ip, for class A and B is a little difficult, but a good and nice help is [here](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=B)

Comment: The calculation is exactly the same for all address classes – as far as address classes are relevant. (Hint: They haven't been relevant for _three decades._ The question of "how many subnets in a class" simply no longer makes any practical sense.)

Comment: (In order for it to work across classes, count bits in _all_ octets – not just in the last one. That's the only thing that changes.)

Answer (score 2):

As you already know from calculating hosts, if you have `n` bits, then you can have `2n` different combinations of those bits. You can use **exactly the same** calculation for subnets as well – at least when all subnets have the same size.

For example, if you have a **/24** network (aka "class C") and want to divide it into equal-size **/29** subnets, you'll be using **29−24 = 5** subnet bits and therefore you have **2<sup>(29−24)</sup> = 2<sup>5</sup> = 32** subnets.

This works regardless of network size; any difference in 'classes' is irrelevant. As another example, if you have a **/16** network and want to divide it into **/27**'s, it'll be **2<sup>(27−16)</sup> = 2<sup>11</sup> = 2048** subnets.

(And if you divide a network into /32's, you'll get the number of hosts the same way!)